# Setting user Agent doesn't work with puppeteer / tor configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I configured a node / puppeteer scraper that successfully bypasses `access denied` for https web pages.

To get around the captcha I configured puppeteer with tor, but that's where I'm running into issues. I configured puppeteer to show me a screenshot when the **scraper** is executed and it shows `access denied`.

I think the issue is that the `User Agent` isn't being set. This is where I am stuck and wondering if anybody else has successfully configured puppeteer with tor to scrape `https` sites?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// Get around client test
const preparePageForTests = async (page) => {
  // Pass the User-Agent Test.
  const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)' +
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.39 Safari/537.36';
  await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'],
    headless: true,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await preparePageForTests(page);

  const testUrl = '<https://www.example.com>';
  await page.goto(testUrl);

  const [response] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(3000),
    page.click('element being clicked'),
  ])

  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // data being scraped
  })

  await browser.close()
})();
```